# Inserting Blank item to database then redirecting to my item view route causes duplicate template elements in DOM

Tags: meteor, iron-router, meteor-blaze

Let's say I have two routes.
One route is a "new Item" route and one is a "view Item" route.
In order to create a blank form I was just inserting a "blank" object into the database and then redirecting to the item view.

I understand this may not be the best way to do this, and I'm open to suggestions because I don't find a lot of tutorials that deal with this paradigm. Most just have a separate input form (which I don't want).

So the **problem** I'm running into is that when I navigate to my `/new` route, it ends up duplicating all the template content in the dom for my `/org` route even though it's just getting redirected to my `/org` route. I can reload the `/org` route all day with different "org data" and it never duplicates anything in my DOM. But the instant I hit that `/new` route button, it will add another set of DOM elements in duplicate fashion.

Can someone help me shed some light on what's going on? Here's my `/new` route code...

```
Router.route('/new/', {
name: 'new',
action: function() {
    var newId = Organizations.insert({
        // Set some defaults
        init_date: new Date(),
        modified_date: new Date()
    });
    this.redirect('/org/' + newId);
} 
});
```

Here's my `/org` route code:

```
Router.route('/org/:_id', {
name: 'org',
subscriptions: function() {
    return [
        Meteor.subscribe('contacts', this.params._id),
        Meteor.subscribe('organization', this.params._id)
    ];
},
onBeforeAction: function() {
    user = Meteor.user();
    if (!Roles.userIsInRole(user, ['admin'])) {
        this.redirect('/submit-ticket');
        this.stop();
    } else {
        this.next();
    }
},
action: function() {
    if (this.ready()) {
        Session.set('currentOrgId', this.params._id);
        this.layout('appLayout');
        this.render('orgHead', {
            to: 'orghead',
            data: function() {
                return Organizations.findOne({
                    _id: this.params._id
                });
            }
        });
        this.render('orgInfo', {
            to: 'content',
            data: function() {
                return Organizations.findOne({
                    _id: this.params._id
                });
            }
        });
    } else {
        this.layout('appLayout');
        this.render('loading', {
            to: 'content'
        });
    }
}
});
```

Comment: This may be a result of my `onRendered` code fighting with Meteor. I have some datepicker widgets being instantiated in my `Temlpate.onRendered` event...

Comment: Yep. It was my datepicker widgets that I was manipulating the DOM with in my onRendered. Not sure it why it doesn't affect things when using the `/org` route over and over, but that redirect seems to cause a mess of things.